# When I run the command sudo apt-get update , I found an error on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, apt, 16.04

```
yugasalabs-26@yugasalabs-26:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for yugasalabs-26: 

Fetched 94.5 kB in 1s (61.3 kB/s)                  
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:2
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical-partners.list` if they as well exist in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If yes remove either the double lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or your remove that `canonical-partner.list` file. Second might be an easier solution.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list has the same repository configured twice.

You can either edit file and remove the duplicated line(2nd line of the file) or remove this reference for being used in graphical mode by removing/unchecking them.

#### Editing the file for removing duplicated repositories

1. Open terminal: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Write `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list`
3. Remove duplicated lines (2nd line of the file).
4. Save file using menu: **file** > **save**
5. Close *gedit*.
6. Now you can try `sudo apt-get update` in terminal again.

#### Disabling/Deleting duplicated repositories in graphical mode

1. In the side menu, click in *System Settings*.
2. In the *System* lane, click in *Software & Updates*.
3. Navigate to *Other Software* tab.
4. Find duplicated repositories and uncheck or delete one of them.
5. Click in *Close*.
6. Click in *Reload*.
7. *Reload* itself is equivalent to `sudo apt-get update`. If everything goes well, you can update whenever you want again!